# DbContext Generator with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: entity-framework, code-generation, t4

I am looking to use EF6 objects directly in my ViewModel and bind directly to them. So I need them to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and use ObservableCollections for the navigation properties.

I also have a ton of existing code implemented as partial classes using OnXXXUpdated to tie in to particular fields updating and OnCreated (or parameterless constructors which conflict  fwith the generated ones) for initialization.

I understand that I can update the *.tt files and there are instructions on how to do that all over the web.

However I was wondering whether there is a centrally maintained version that someone was maintaining with just that basic added functionality. Kind of like the twitter bootstrap of EF T4 templates. That way I know its following best practices and that I didn't forget to consider something obvious and I will be able to download new versions as EF progresses.